# How many difficulty modes does Dark Souls 1 have?

Tags: pc, dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls 1 and I'm in Dark Souls ++. Are there other difficulty modes beyond that?

Comment: I hope not because I can not kill the Four Kings in New London, I think his weak point is fire but I can't kill them.

Comment: Stay close to them, so they don't use ranged attacks. Stick on the first that spawns and just hack away at him (while still dodging his attack ofcourse). The most important part of the fight is to do enough damage so you can kill one of the kings before the next one spawns. While they have a weakness to fire, it's only worth using a fire weapon if it fits with your build (since the bonus damage from fire isn't high enough to justify using a weaker weapon). So just take your highest-damage weapon and chop away.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "++" you are seeing are known as [New Game Plus](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/new-game-plus) and the difficulty increase with each run through up to 6 times

> After the ending of the game a new game will start. This is called New Game Plus (NG+). New Game Plus begins after you have defeated the final boss, Gwyn, Lord Of Cinder. The game begins again, allowing you to keep most of your gear and items, but with increased difficulty. After NG+ is completed, the game will continue onto NG+2 with slightly increased difficulty again. **This continues all the way to "New Game Plus 6" (NG++++++)**

Aside from enemies being stronger in general, the following are the changes in enemy HP and dropped souls between each new NG+

```
1st NG       Regular NG values
2nd NG+      Enemy HP and Souls increase by inconsistent amounts.
3rd NG+2     Enemy HP and Souls are 7% greater than NG+ values.
4th NG+3     Enemy HP and Souls are 10% greater than NG+ values.
5th NG+4     Enemy HP and Souls are 14% greater than NG+ values.
6th NG+5     Enemy HP and Souls are 19% greater than NG+ values.
7th NG+6     Enemy HP and Souls are 25% greater than NG+ values.
```

Comment: Oh great, I still have a long way to go!!! Is it the same with Dark Souls 2 and 3? Or change the parameters?

Comment: @Frostmus I think so, but I can't say for certain

Comment: I can't speak for 1 or 2 but DS3 is said to have unlimited NG+ cycles, but with a difficulty cap around NG+7.

Comment: @Frostmus DS2 has some additional content in NG+, subsequent cycles are just bigger numbers. DS3 works like DS1.

Answer (score 3):

You can go up to NG+6 with a linear increase in difficulty after Ng+2, but otherwise there's no difficulty modes.

More details in the [wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/new-game-plus).